# Unable to verify the first certificate while testing POST API using Postman

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, postman

I am writing a POST API which needs authorization in order to post something. When I test the POST API, I get 200 OK status but It shows me home page(login page) in response. I have already disabled SSL Certificate verification.

Here is the controller

```
using GigHub.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace GigHub.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]  
    public class AttendancesController : ApiController
    {

        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public AttendancesController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }



        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GET()
        {
            return Ok("Hi there");

        }

        //POST API
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Attend([FromBody]int gigId)
        {
            var attendance = new Attendance()
            {
                GigId = gigId,
                AttendeeId = User.Identity.GetUserId()
            };

            _context.Attendances.Add(attendance);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the response and error I get,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AZAc.png)

When I remove the [Authorize] code above class and test the get api,
my api is working fine. The problem arised when I put [Authorize]

Comment: Authorize attribute verifies if the incoming request is authenticated and authorized or not. I am not sure what type of authentication you have enabled in your project but it is clear that the request you send via postman is not authenticated as per the Authorize attribute and that's why it is redirecting you to the login page. Can you tell us why are you using Authorize Attribute on the Controller? What type of validation you wish to do for the request coming to your API?

Comment: I need an authorization in an app because user can create an event and his userid or name will also be automatically stored in database.

Comment: What's the authorization mechanism you are using? Does the user login somewhere before accessing the API?

Comment: Yes, user needs to login to webapp.